# Getting the ViewModel in to display information in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

So I am a bit stuck with how to create the ViewModel and pass it into my composable so that I can use the Data Class models to display on the textView.

Here's the code

MainActivity

```
private const val TAG = "MainActivity"
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val viewModel: PokemonListViewModel by viewModels()

        setContent {
//            val pokemon = viewModel.pokemon.value
          PokeDexComposeTheme {
              Surface(
                  modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                  color = Color.Cyan) {

                PokemonListScreen()
              }
          }

        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun PokemonListScreen(viewModel: PokemonListViewModel){
 //Tried this method as well
 val pokemon by viewModel.pokemonLiveData.observeAsState("")
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            ClickableText(
                text = AnnotatedString(),
                onClick = {offset ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "PokemonListScreen: clicked")
                },
                )

            Divider(
                Modifier.padding(start = 24.dp, end = 24.dp),
                color = Color.Black,
                thickness = 2.dp
            )
        }
    }



@Composable
fun PokemonDetails(){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
           fontSize = 25.sp,
            text = "NAME: "
        )
        Text(
            fontSize = 50.sp,
            text = "NameModel"
        )
        Divider(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 24.dp, end = 24.dp),
            color = Color.Black,
            thickness = 1.dp
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
            fontSize = 25.sp,
            text = "HEIGHT: "
        )
        Text(
            fontSize = 50.sp,
            text = "HeightModel"
        )
        Divider(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 24.dp, end = 24.dp),
            color = Color.Black,
            thickness = 1.dp
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
            fontSize = 25.sp,
            text = "WEIGHT: "
        )
        Text(
            fontSize = 50.sp,
            text = "WeightModel"
        )
        Divider(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 24.dp, end = 24.dp),
            color = Color.Black,
            thickness = 1.dp
        )

    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
class PokemonListViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val repository = PokemonRepository(PokemonApplication.pokemonListDatabase.pokemonDao)




init {
    fetchPokemonNames()
}


    private fun fetchPokemonNames(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val fetchPokeListEntity = repository.getAllPokemonNames()
                pokemon.value = fetchPokeListEntity
        }
    }


}
```

I am pretty new to Jetpack Compose, so my mindset was applying the viewModels the same way I would with regular XML layouts. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What specifically isn't working?

Comment: I can't seem to connect the viewModel to the Composable, so that I can access the Data Class and populate the TextView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I picked up some courses on Udemy, and StateFlow was the method used to replace MutableLiveData.

```
class PokemonListViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val repository = PokemonRepository(PokemonApplication.pokemonListDatabase.pokemonDao)

    private val _pokemonStateData = MutableStateFlow<List<PokeListEntity>?>(emptyList())
    val pokemonStateData = _pokemonStateData.asStateFlow()


    init {
        fetchPokemonNames()
    }


    fun fetchPokemonNames(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val fetchPokeListEntity = repository.getAllPokemonNames()
            _pokemonStateData.value = fetchPokeListEntity
        }
    }


}
```

All I had to do was to use StateFlow and set up the ViewModel inside the Composeable properly. And it ended up working perfectly.

```
@Composable
fun PokemonListPage(
    pokemonViewModel: PokemonListViewModel = viewModel(), //<- adding viewModel as a parameter 
    navController: NavController){

    val pokeList = pokemonViewModel.pokemonStateData.collectAsState().value //<- creating a variable for the StateFlow variable

    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        Scaffold(topBar =
        {
            TopAppBar(
                backgroundColor = Color.DarkGray,
                elevation = 0.dp,
            ) {
                Row(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ){
                    Text(
                        text = "POKEDEX",
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        fontSize = 25.sp,
                        color = Color.Magenta
                    )
                }
            }
        }, backgroundColor = Color.DarkGray){
            PokemonCards(pokemons = pokeList!!, navController = navController) //<- setting that variable to another composable which is leveraging the info from the viewModel 
        }
```

[image]

Comment: hello, i am facing the same issue here. how do you pass the viewmodel information to the compose? could you please share that

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. There's two ways you can go about this. Either you use `LiveData` and upload the dependency to allow `LiveData` to be used in Compose or You use `StateFlow` (highly recommended). `StateFlow` is the better version of `LiveData` and is actually meant for Compose. Simply set up `StateFlow` like you would with `LiveData`, then on the compose that is using the viewModel, have the viewmodel as a parameter and set it to a variable. Then use that variable and connect it to where you need to connect it. I'll leave some code of the Main Composable up for you to see how it works